# Can you have a gradient as a button tintColor?

Tags: swift, gradient, tintcolor

I have a icon asset in interface builder which I have as my button image.  I can change the colour of it using

```
button.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Can I apply a gradient though to a tintColor property?

UPDATE

For clarity, my png image icon has different shapes, heart, camera, which I have set up as template images. They all have transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert `CAGradientLayer` into your button and apply the tintColor.

Another way is to subclass the UIButton, and in drawRect, use CoreGraphics to draw the gradient effect like:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    ... 
    // setup up your tint color for startColor, endColor
    drawLinearGradient(context, rect, startColor, endColor);
}
```

If you have a transparent background, you can use your view's layer's `mask` property to achieve gradient.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. My icon is a heart with a transparent background, would the above need me to draw the path of the heart and fill it?

Comment: I wasn't specific as have lots of different icons for different buttons. Only got specific to help clarify answer. Instead of being rude, why not help out? Your comment is not needed nor wanted. I don't post unless I have searched. @matt

Comment: @TravelNVal if you know who is matt then you would not say that. knowing how to search and solve are important. Your question is not clear enough indeed. If you have a transparent background, you can use your view's layer's mask property to achieve gradient. I believe the keywords in my answer has given you the direction to start google and code

Comment: I know who Matt is, still not a response that is appreciated. Been teaching myself swift for 3 months, learnt tons from here and the web, sometimes don't even know what to search for. Will try layer... Thank you. Updates question, will close as answered, thanks.