# Gradient tint color in segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, gradient, segmentedcontrol

I get gradient image with this method

```
func gradient(size:CGSize,color:[UIColor]) -> UIImage?{
    //turn color into cgcolor
    let colors = color.map{$0.cgColor}
    //begin graphics context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    // From now on, the context gets ended if any return happens
    defer {UIGraphicsEndImageContext()}
    //create core graphics context
    let locations:[CGFloat] = [0.0,1.0]
    guard let gredient = CGGradient.init(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors as NSArray as CFArray, locations: locations) else {
        return nil
    }
    //draw the gradient
    context.drawLinearGradient(gredient, start: CGPoint(x:0.0,y:size.height), end: CGPoint(x:size.width,y:size.height), options: [])
    // Generate the image (the defer takes care of closing the context)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

Then I set tintColor of segmented control to gradient:

```
    let gradientImage = gradient(size: listSegmentedControl.frame.size, color: [UIColor.black, UIColor.red])!
    listSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage)
```

and that doesn't work. However, same code works for setting backgroundColor:

```
    let gradientImage = gradient(size: listSegmentedControl.frame.size, color: [UIColor.black, UIColor.red])!
    listSegmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage)
```

Does anybody have any ideas why? I really need to set gradient tintColor. Any help is very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Ideally I want my segmented control to look like this:

[image]

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733943/can-you-have-a-gradient-as-a-button-tintcolor

Comment: @Dopapp thanks! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known hack to change the tint color of `UISegmentedControl`

```
   let sortedViews = listSegmentedControl.subviews.sorted( by: { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )

    for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerated() {
        if index == listSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
            view.tintColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage)
        } else {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.gray //Whatever the color of non selected segment controller tab
        }
    }
```

Though looks like a ugly hack, I have been using it from a quite a while and seems fairly straight forward. Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

Is this what you need buddy?

[image]

If yes lemme know, Ill post the code for the same.

**EDIT 2:**

As OP has mentioned in his comment that the output he is expecting is same as the one I showed in image above, providing code for the same.

**Disclaimer:**

As mentioned by [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) in his comments below, this is a hack and makes use of undocumented (Complete public API though) but a very well known hack to change the tint color of UISegemntedControl that exists from as far as iOS 5 (Thats how I remember, lemme know if I am wrong )

So use answer with the caution in mind that, in future releases of iOS Apple *might* change the structure of subviews in `UISegemntedControl` and might affect your O/P. Nothing that I can see, will result in crash but might affect the way O/P is rendered on screen.

I have declared a variable so that GradientImage can be generated only once, but its up to your implementation to use it the way you want

```
var gradientImage : UIImage! = nil
```

In `ViewDidLoad` I initialize the `gradientImage` and `UISegmentedControl` as

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gradientImage = gradient(size: segmentControl.frame.size, color: [UIColor.black, UIColor.red])!

        //I have specified custom font need not necessarily be used
        //Font color attribute is important though, usually `UISegementedControl` title takes color from tint color, because we might need a different color for text to highlight above gradient color am using custom font colors

        let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 20)
        segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : font!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue], for: .normal)
        segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white], for: .selected)

        //Set the border color and border to `UISegmentedControl` and also make it round corner

        segmentControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage).cgColor
        segmentControl.layer.borderWidth = 2
        segmentControl.layer.masksToBounds = true
        segmentControl.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        //In order to update the selected Segment tint and background color we need to call multiple statements every time selection changes hence I have moved it to the function and called it in viewDidLoad

        updateGradientBackground()
    }
```

Finally updateGradientBackground function definition is same as the one I posted in my original answer

```
fileprivate func updateGradientBackground() {
        let sortedViews = segmentControl.subviews.sorted( by: { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )
        for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerated() {
            if index == segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
                //very important thing to notice here is because tint color was not honoring the `UIColor(patternImage` I rather used `backgroundColor` to create the effect and set clear color as clear color
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: self.gradientImage)
                view.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            } else {
                //very important thing to notice here is because tint color was not honoring the `UIColor(patternImage` I rather used `backgroundColor` to create the effect and set clear color as clear color
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //Whatever the color of non selected segment controller tab
                view.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, in IBAction of UISegmentedControl, simply call

```
@IBAction func segmentControllerTapped(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    self.updateGradientBackground()
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please note that this code depends on the undocumented and private subview structure of `UISegmentedControl`. This code could fail with any iOS update that changes that private subview structure. At least is shouldn't crash.

Comment: @rmaddy : Agreed. Hence I mentioned it as a ugly hack. A hack that works for now but runs with a potential danger of breaking in future, that being said this hack seems to be working fine from iOS5-6 till now. Not mentioning anything in defense of my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I implemented your code in my app and it doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong.. Can you please check it from your side and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: @lavrin-pristazh : Checking now

Comment: @lavrin-pristazh : But dude the gradient you provided does not have same color effect, with the gradient you provided out put you get is what I posted above

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the gradient I provided was just for testing purposes. My problem is that I cannot get that frame around unselected segment, and corners are not rounded.

Comment: @lavrin-pristazh : Take a look at the updated image, dont worry about the squared corner, u can make it rounded :)

Comment: Yeah, that's want I need. If you shared your code you'd help me a lot and I'll accept your answer

Comment: @lavrin-pristazh : gimme a minute updating answer

Comment: @lavrin-pristazh : Updated my answer, read the comments carefully

Comment: @lavrin-pristazh : Thanks a lot buddy :) Happy coding :)

Comment: I just changed your code a little and set up my segmented control exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much, you saved my day :)

Comment: @lavrin-pristazh : Am glad I could be of help :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Implemented gradient color for knob on iOS13+ UISegmentControl. Added subview with gradient then set mask to it and copying animations to match original knob.

```swift
// 1 - Make subclass
class GradientSegment: UISegmentedControl {
    // this could be UIImageView
    lazy var gradientView: GradientView = {
        let view = GradientView(frame: self.bounds)
        view.startColor = ...
        view.endColor = ...
        view.horizontalMode = true
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        return view
    }()

    let gradientMask = UIImageView()

    // 2 - override init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        addSubview(gradientView)
        gradientView.mask = gradientMask
    }

    // 3 - Copy knob position and animations
    override func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, at index: Int) {
        super.insertSubview(view, at: index)
        if index == 3, let view = view as? UIImageView {
            gradientMask.image = view.image
            gradientMask.frame = view.frame

            if let keys = view.layer.animationKeys() {
                for key in keys {
                    guard let animation = view.layer.animation(forKey: key) else {
                        continue
                    }
                    gradientMask.layer.add(animation, forKey: key)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not safe approach, because appearance will become invalid when apple will change control layout, but for now it is working.