# Apply gradient to segmented control's "overlay"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to apply a gradient to a segmented control. So far, I've achieved the following:
[image: example]

**How can I apply the gradient solely to the currently dark blue colored part and the control's border?**

Code:

```
let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)
let sndColor = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 178/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)

segmentedControl.applyGradient(colours: [color, sndColor], locations: [0.0, 1.0])
```

Comment: write a custom view.

Comment: @Sulthan Could you please detail your answer in a further answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradient tint color in segmented control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140891/gradient-tint-color-in-segmented-control)