# customizing UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Trying to customize a UISegmentedControl to have the following designs:

[image: Gold Segment]

[image: Platinum Segment]

However, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to customize the UISegmentedControl to look like this.  When I set a background image as a gradient the title is removed, and if i set a title the image is removed.  Nor am i sure how to use a divider image to make that middle portion.  Is there a different way to do this ? (it doesn't have to be a UISegmentedControl if there is an easier way to do this without)

Comment: is image your requirement? why can't you use colors instead of images

Comment: @RajuAbe there isn't a way to set the background using the segmentedcontrol api with a gradient color as far as i can tell

Comment: @daredevil1234 did you look at this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51141179/1244403